# R-Module Homomorphism from $I\otimes I$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $I = (2,x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

[image]

Hello everyone, can someone tell me how to prove part(c).This is my atempt:

Define $\Phi: I\otimes I \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ by $\Phi(p(x) \otimes q(x))= \frac{p(0)}{2}*q'(0)$, where $q'$ denotes the usual derivative. Now, i was able to show that:

$$\Phi[(p_1(x)+p_2(x)) \otimes (q_1(x)+q_2(x))] = (\frac{p_1(0)+p_2(0)}{2})*q_1'(0) + (\frac{p_1(0)+p_2(0)}{2})*q_2'(0) = \Phi[(p_1(x)+p_2(x)) \otimes q_1(x)]+ \Phi[(p_1(x)+p_2(x)) \otimes q_2(x)]$$

On the other hand, let $r(x)\in R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Can someone help me to prove that:

$$\Phi(r(x)p(x)\otimes q(x)) = r(x)\Phi(p(x)\otimes q(x))$$

Thanks

Comment: But what you want us to help you prove cannot be true, since the left-hand side is an element in $\Bbb Z_2$, and the right-hand side is the product of an integral polynomial with an element in $\Bbb Z_2$, whatever that means.

Comment: @Arthur I posted the whole exercise...to see if that helps

Comment: But if you've done b), then c) is solved just by saying "The $R$-bilinear map $I\times I\to \Bbb Z_2$ indices a unique map $I\otimes I\to \Bbb Z_2$ by the universal property of tensor products." Note that $\frac{p(0)}{2}q'(0)$ is exactly $\frac {a_0}{2}b_1$.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur, now i get it